# order by returns error in a union clause

Tags: mysql, union

I'm using this query it's working without ordering data but after adding order by the query returns an error

```
(SELECT * FROM bills INNER JOIN cats INNER JOIN suppliers
INNER JOIN new_cards
WHERE new_cards.`Card_Code` LIKE '%8%'
AND bills.`Sup_ID` = suppliers.`Sup_ID`
AND new_cards.`Sup_ID`  = suppliers.`Sup_ID`
AND cats.`Cat_ID` = bills.`Cat_ID`
AND bills.`Cat_ID` = cats.`Cat_ID`
AND new_cards.`Bill_ID` = bills.`Bill_ID`)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM bills INNER JOIN cats INNER JOIN suppliers
INNER JOIN sold_cards WHERE
sold_cards.`Card_Code` LIKE '%8%'
AND bills.`Sup_ID` = suppliers.`Sup_ID`
AND sold_cards.`Sup_ID`  = suppliers.`Sup_ID`
AND cats.`Cat_ID` = bills.`Cat_ID`
AND bills.`Cat_ID` = cats.`Cat_ID`
AND sold_cards.`Bill_ID` = bills.`Bill_ID`)
ORDER BY bills.`ID` DESC
```

here's the error
    Table 'bills' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd recommend selecting your column names out.  That way, you know that both queries return the same number of columns.  Then you can just `ORDER BY ID DESC`.

To get yours to work correctly, identify the bills id column in each union and then order by it (without referencing a table name):

```
(SELECT bills.id billsid, <<other columns>> FROM bills INNER JOIN cats INNER JOIN suppliers
INNER JOIN new_cards
WHERE new_cards.`Card_Code` LIKE '%8%'
AND bills.`Sup_ID` = suppliers.`Sup_ID`
AND new_cards.`Sup_ID`  = suppliers.`Sup_ID`
AND cats.`Cat_ID` = bills.`Cat_ID`
AND bills.`Cat_ID` = cats.`Cat_ID`
AND new_cards.`Bill_ID` = bills.`Bill_ID`)
UNION
(SELECT bills.id billsid, <<other columns>> FROM bills INNER JOIN cats INNER JOIN suppliers
INNER JOIN sold_cards WHERE
sold_cards.`Card_Code` LIKE '%8%'
AND bills.`Sup_ID` = suppliers.`Sup_ID`
AND sold_cards.`Sup_ID`  = suppliers.`Sup_ID`
AND cats.`Cat_ID` = bills.`Cat_ID`
AND bills.`Cat_ID` = cats.`Cat_ID`
AND sold_cards.`Bill_ID` = bills.`Bill_ID`)
ORDER BY billsid DESC
```

---

Personally, I'd recommend rewriting your query as follows:

```
SELECT b.id billsid, other columns 
FROM bills b
    INNER JOIN cats c ON c.`Cat_ID` = b.`Cat_ID`
    INNER JOIN suppliers s ON b.`Sup_ID` = s.`Sup_ID`
    INNER JOIN new_cards nc ON nc.`Sup_ID`  = s.`Sup_ID` 
                               AND nc.`Bill_ID` = b.`Bill_ID`
WHERE nc.`Card_Code` LIKE '%8%'
UNION
SELECT b.id billsid, other columns
FROM bills b 
    INNER JOIN cats c ON c.`Cat_ID` = b.`Cat_ID`
    INNER JOIN suppliers s ON b.`Sup_ID` = s.`Sup_ID`
    INNER JOIN sold_cards sc ON sc.`Sup_ID`  = s.`Sup_ID` 
                              AND sc.`Bill_ID` = b.`Bill_ID`
WHERE sc.`Card_Code` LIKE '%8%'
ORDER BY billsid DESC
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM bills INNER JOIN cats INNER JOIN suppliers
INNER JOIN new_cards
WHERE n' at line 1

Comment: @Yasser -- I don't think you can use `*` in your select list if you've defined another field.  As mentioned in my comment, you should just list out the column names.